# minitest racktest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, rails-api, rack-test

Does anybody have any examples of using minitest and reacktest together to create request specs?

I want to be able to request a resource:

`get '/api/resource', format: :json`

And then test the response.

Comment: Could [this gem](https://github.com/brandonweiss/rack-minitest) be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use rack-test, as you suggested! Write your specs/unit-tests and with rack-test you can do:

```
def test_api_ressource_json
    get "/api/resource.json"

    assert last_response.ok?
    assert last_response.body.include?("something")

    # Test whatever you like with last_response.body
end
```

And that should be it.

Comment: In Rails 4.2, including `require rails/test_help` first, say in your `test_helper.rb` file in the `test` folder, and then adding the Rack Test mixin via `include Rack::Test::Methods` inside your test class, is needed for tests to run using Rack's mock testing infrastructure. Then you get helper methods like `last_response`, `post`, `get`, etc.